# difference between Executor framework & Message queues like JMS

Tags: java, asynchronous, message-queue, executorservice

Message queues are primarily used for executing asynchronous tasks on the server & I recently read about the Executor framework which also does the same thing spawns & manages threads to execute asynchronous tasks. Can anyone tell me the difference between the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primary difference is that the Executor framework is for intra-program task queueing and execution, whereas JMS is for queuing between different programs (typically) on different machines.

Other differences include:

- JMS queues are (or can be) persistent, where as Executor, etcetera are in-memory only.
- JMS queues can (I believe) be used in a transactional system, where as Executor, etcetera can't.  (In part, that is a consequence of the persistent / non-persistent distinction.)

---

> So that means if my app is not distributed I can use Executor framework.

Maybe ...

> For an instance I want to code a fb style notification system & publish subscribe will the use of executor framework be fitting for that? I assume the code will be on the same machine in a single db.

Well the problem is that the standard implementations of the Executor framework don't put the task queues into a database.  They are just light-weight in-memory data structures.  They don't *persist* if your application is restarted.

Now, I suppose you *could* write your Executor / ExecutorService class that put the queue into a database.  But why bother?  It would be simpler to use JMS or similar ...

Comment: So that means if my app is not distributed I can use Executor framework. For an instance I want to code a fb style notification system & publish subscribe will the use of executor framework be fitting for that? I assume the code will be on the same machine in a single db

Comment: a jms framework might also support failover, load-balancing, retry on failure, move to another queue on too many failures...

Comment: ... none of which make a lot of sense in the scenarios that executors are designed for.